# Expected value question, visiting a candy shop and randomly selecting flavors

Tags: probability

Bob visits a candy store that has 20 different flavors of candy. Each visit, he randomly chooses a flavor and the probability of choosing a particular flavor is the same for any flavor. He visits the store for a total of 14 visits, what is the expected number of flavors he has tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Big hint / Setup:**

Let the flavors be labeled $1,2,3,\dots,20$.

Let $X_i = \begin{cases}0&\text{if flavor i has not been picked in the visits}\\ 1&\text{if flavor i has been picked at least once in the visits}\end{cases}$

Let $X = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{20} X_i$

Notice that $X$ represents the total number of different flavors he has tried.

What is $Pr(X_i=0)$?  What is $Pr(X_i=1)$?  What is $E[X_i]$?

> $Pr(X_i=0)$ corresponds to *every visit* he picks a flavor other than flavor $i$.  What is the chance of that happening each visit?  In successive visits?

Now...using the linearity of expectation, we have

$E[X] = E[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{20} X_i] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{20} E[X_i] = \dots$